# Downloading over wifi is strange

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

The situation is basically as follows:
If I download a file (e.g. a ubuntu.iso) through ethernet on my homeserver I get 2 MB/s.
If I transfer the file over wifi to my laptop, I get about 1.8 MB/s

However if I download the same file and my laptop in the same position, I only get 120 KB/s

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Without having information like speed of your internet or wireless connection and signalstrength it is hard to tell, but i try to give you some ideas.

- 1.8Mbit could me the max of your wifi 802.11b
- 2Mbit could be the max of your internet and if downloading it over cable and wifi, cable gets more bandwith in your case.

Comment: The issue is that if I download a file over internet through wifi I get low speeds but both my wifi connection and connection to the internet are fast in comparison. The wireless is 802.11n dual bnad

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood your initial question... Try to make some tests on http://speedtest.net and post the results here.

Comment: http://24.24.174.153/mxshare/FolderMisc/superuser.png